# dojox.form.manager not working in programmatic tab container

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dojo

When I open the below "html", in the programmatic dynamic tab container, I am unable to get the dojox.form.Manager object in the javascript. the form object below is undefined.
Please suggest me if I am missing anything.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" title="Admin" selected="true"     href="sample.html">
</div>

<form data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Manager" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="">
    <table style="border: 1px solid #9f9f9f;" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="firstname">Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" dojo-data-id="firstname" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" name="firstname" trim="true" id="firstname" propercase="true" ></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
      require(["dijit/registry","dojo/ready"], function(registry,ready) {
        ready(function() { 
            var obj = JSESSION['group'];
            var form = registry.byId("myForm");
            alert(form);
            form.setFormValues(obj);
        });
    }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it temp. I have used Dojo.xhrPost to send the request to the dummy page. After receiving the response from the dummy page, I have set the form values.